# Divisibility between polynomial expressions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, quadratic-residues

Given the expression

$$ x = \frac{n^2 -bn+c}{(2n+k)-b}$$

For $b$ and $c$ integer coefficients, $k$ is any integer constant, and index $-\infty <n<\infty$,

**1.** What is the relationship that must exist between the coefficients $b$ and $c$ so that, at any constant $k$, $x$ will be a sequence of integers generated by the index $n$?

**2.** As a consequence, why there is no solution for $b=c≠0$?

I suppose it is better to divide the solutions between $k=\text{even}$ and $k=\text{odd}$.

Comment: Is $k$ allowed to depend on $b$ and $c$, or are you looking for $(b,c)$ pairs that will work no matter which $k$ we choose?

Comment: $k$ is independent from the quadratic coefficients.

Comment: OK. So, let's allow be dependent for k=even and k=odd.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no possible choice** of $b,c,k$ at all such that
$$ x_n = \frac{n^2-bn+c}{2n+k-b} $$
is an integer for every integer $n$.

To see this, temporarily switch variable to $u=n+k/2-b/2$. Our expression now has the form
$$ x(u) = \frac{u^2+pu+q}{2u} $$
for some real constants $p$ and $q$ that we don't need to find explicitly. If we allow $u$ to be real (i.e. not necessarily an integer), differentiating this gives
$$ \frac{dx}{du} = \frac12 - \frac{q}{2u^2} $$
which converges to $\frac12$ when $u\to\infty$. So for $u$ large enough we always have, say, $\frac13 < \frac{dx}{du} < \frac23 $, and therefore by the mean value theorem, $\frac13 < x(u+1)-x(u) < \frac23$.

Switching back to the original variable $n$, we see that $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is exactly something of the form $x(u+1)-x(u)$. But if $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ are both integers, their difference *cannot* lie between $\frac13$ and $\frac23$.

Comment: A refreshing argument!